# Gradle script xml transformation

Tags: android, regex, xml, gradle

I'm writting a gradle script and i need to modify my androidManifest in this script.
I don't know how to do that, i need to change 2 properties in this manifest.

I have tried to use a regEx with a ant.replaceregexp but i can't write my regEx to replace only the android:name of the activity node.

There is a better way to modify it or no ?

Maybe i can use a XML parser but i don't know how to write my file after.

Here you can find my manifest :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10402" android:versionName="1.4.2" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <!--GradleActivity--><activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="xxxxxx" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx.TrackingService">
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx.BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <permission android:name="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.yyyyyy.xxxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I want to change the " < activity> =>android:name = xxxxx" property to " < activity> =>android:name = zzzzzzz"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with groups:

```
/(<activity.*android:name=")(\w+)(.*">)/gm
```

And this subtitution:

```
\1zzzzz\3
```

Link:

https://regex101.com/r/vI7sK3/5

Comment: so if i want to use that i have to do that  : ant.replaceRegexp(file:'manifest.xml', match: '/(<activity.*android:name=")(\w+)(.*">)/gm', replace : '\1zzzzz\3')
Or the is an other syntax to do that ?

Comment: Seems like you have to adapt the regex to ant.replaceRegex syntaxis according http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.4/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ReplaceRegExp.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html